# NodeJS : How to save a rendered view as a static .html file?

Tags: html, node.js, file, express, swig-template

i'm using NodeJS for a school project and I have to generate a dynamic html page with Express and swig variables. But here comes the problem: I have to save the rendered view with the variables replaced by their content as a static `.html` file.

I tried to read the documentation about FS but I found nothing about taking a whole html page and put the html code inside a file. The only way I found was to "Right-click" and "save as" but that's not how I'm supposed to do it.

Any ideas or suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `swig` templating engine then we need to get the output of the Swig template first:

```
var swig  = require('swig');
var template = swig.compileFile('/path/to/your/template.html');
var output = template({
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

Now that you have the output, we can use `fs` to save the html:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/path/to/destination.html", output, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Side note: [Swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig) is NOT MAINTAINED anymore and has got security holes.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!
I know about swig being not maintained but it's a group project and this is the final choice we had